# Rails association nil in after_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models with a one to many association. I want to set a default value on the child model at initialization based on some state of the parent. This involves having an after_initialize callback fire on the child that needs to access the parent through the belongs_to association. The problem is that when I instantiate the child using the build method, the association to the parent is nil in the after_initialize callback. Is this expected behaviour? I'm on rails 3.0.6

A toy example:

```
class Merchant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :merchant

    after_initialize :set_default_value

    def set_default_value
        if merchant.state
            self.foo = some_value
        else
            self.foo = some_other_value
        end
    end
end
```

And in a controller:

```
product = merchant.products.build
```

In the call to set_default_value, merchant is nil though it seems that it shouldn't be.

Comment: Has the original merchant instance been saved yet, before you call merchant.products.build?

Comment: Yes the merchant would be an existing record in the db so it would have a valid id.

Comment: I tried it almost exactly how you have it and it worked for me. Only difference is that `class Products` should be `class Product` without the `s`.

Comment: Right sorry that was a typo in the question. Edited that. mu and Chris, when you say that it worked for you, did you check the merchant id inside the callback or after the build in the resulting object? In my situation the merchant id is correct in the resulting product object, but nil in the callback.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would change the code as follows:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def set_default_value(state = merchant.state)
    if state
      self.foo = some_value
    else
      self.foo = some_other_value
    end
  end
end
```

Then change your caller to:

```
product = merchant.products.build(:state => merchant.state)
```

Also, I've found after_initialize callbacks to be slow.  So another option is to move the logic into the builder for the product.

```
product = merchant.products.build(:foo => merchant.state ? some_value : some_other_value)
```

This also eliminates the Law of Demeter violation from the code (i.e. the Product shouldn't know/care what the merchant's state is).

Answer (score 0):

I am on rails 2.3 and I can confirm that

```
product = merchant.products.build
```

will not return the correct merchant_id association in an after_initialize callback

but I've found that it will work correctly with

```
product = merchant.products.new
```

I think it was fixed with this commit (I don't really know though, I am not really familiar the git workflow):

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1842

Because in rails 3.1.11 it works for both `build` and `new`

Answer (score 0):

You likely look for `inverse_of`

```
has_many :products, inverse_of: :merchant
```

Comment: Why are they looking for `inverse_of`?